# Validation gone wrong

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a textinput that accept any numbers that are dividable by 500 examples 1000, 1500, 2000, 2500 3000, etc. if the user write 12263 it should display 12000 if the user write 12789 it should be 12500

I have this code, but it doesnt work at all, at some numbers work fine, but with other it just go to the max number

vPayrollBureauMaxOffer: is the max number that can be accepted i get this value from an api vPayrollAmount: is the amount the user writ in the textinput 3000 is the min value accepted if the user write a number less than 3000 it should change to 3000

as an example let say that the max number is 250000, when i write 50000 it goes to 250000 if I write 4000 it also goes to 250000, i have seen that this only happens with numbers that are less than 100000
i dont know what happens

this is my code

```
    const validatePayroll = () => {
    if(vPayrollAmount <= 3000){
      return setvPayrollAmount((3000));
    }
    if(vPayrollAmount >= vPayrollBureauMaxOffer){
      return setvPayrollAmount(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer);
    }
    if((vPayrollAmount >= 3000) && (vPayrollAmount <= vPayrollBureauMaxOffer)){
      return setvPayrollAmount(Math.floor(vPayrollAmount / 500.0) * 500.0);
    }
  };  

<TextInput
   style={styles.inputs}
   placeholder={vPayrollAmount.toString}
   placeholderTextColor={theme.SECONDARY_TEXT_COLOR}
   keyboardType={'numeric'}
   underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
   autoCorrect={false}
   autoCapitalize="characters"
   value={vPayrollAmount}
   onBlur={() => validatePayroll(vPayrollAmount)}
   onChangeText={setvPayrollAmount}
   />
```

Comment: Why you have this onChangeText thing? What is the purpose?

Comment: To set the value of vPayrollAmount given by the user

Comment: You are already doing that onBlur. With validatePayrollAmount

Comment: I would suggest using only one event onBlur or onChangeText whichever you like to do your validation. And use a reference using useRef to get the current value of the element to compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like you have `vPayrollBureauMaxOffer = "250000";` when it needs to be `vPayrollBureauMaxOffer = 250000;` and it is doing string comparison, where `"50000" > "250000"`, but `50000 < 250000`.

Quick solution is to just do:

```
const validatePayroll = () => {
  if(vPayrollAmount <= 3000){
    return setvPayrollAmount((3000));
  }
  if(vPayrollAmount >= parseInt(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer)){
    return setvPayrollAmount(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer);
  }
  if((vPayrollAmount >= 3000) && (vPayrollAmount <= parseInt(vPayrollBureauMaxOffer))) {
    return setvPayrollAmount(Math.floor(vPayrollAmount / 500.0) * 500.0);
  }
};  

onBlur={() => validatePayroll(parseInt(vPayrollAmount))}
```

Comment: Doesn't javascript automatically typecast a string to number when it is compared with a number?

Comment: Why would the other one be a number?  It's coming from a `TextInput` - `if(vPayrollAmount >= vPayrollBureauMaxOffer){`

Comment: Yeah that is text. But you are comparing it with either 3000 or 250000. Both are numbers. So javascript should typecast the textinput value to number while the comparison happens. If it is not a valid number. It'll convert it to NaN

Comment: actually this solved the problem, thanks a lot

Comment: No, if you do `console.log("5" > "40")` you will get true, but if either one is *actually* a number it will be false (`5 > "40"` or `"5" > 40`)